# Duplicate unique value [Acg Filter Chain Proxy] declared for identity constraint "web-app-filter-name-uniqueness" of element "web-app"

Tags: web.xml

```
In my web.xml i have the following format. While deploying in jboss it is throwing me
```

Duplicate unique value [Acg Filter Chain Proxy] declared for identity constraint "web-app-filter-name-uniqueness" of element "web-app".

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Acg Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.acgsecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBean</param-name>
        <param-value>filterChainProxy</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Acg Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rmServices/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Acg Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.acgsecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBean</param-name>
        <param-value>filterChainProxy</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Acg Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/remoting/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can i avoid this error. Can anyone please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have just one definition for `filter` and have multiple `<filter-mappings>`